# Getting an error while trying to access property from an extern Controller in Xcode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios

In a first controller, I create an instance variable for my model, because I want to edit its content from a controller and then access the same object from another controller.

In the second controller, I get an error when trying to access the object:

Property 'levels' not found on object of type FirstController.

*Model.h*
    #imports....

```
@property (readwrite,copy) NSMutableString *answersString;
```

*FirstController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Model.h"

@interface FirstController : UIViewController{
 // some declarations
   }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) LevelsCompleted *levels;


   @end
```

*FirstController.m*

```
   #import "FirstController.h"

@interface FirstController(){
//stuff
}
@end

@implementation FirstController
@synthesize levels;
 //stuff
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {   // This is the changeAnswerString method
    if (levels ==nil) self.levels = [[LevelsCompleted alloc]init];
    self.levels.answersString=@"1";
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];


}
@end
```

*SecondController.m*

```
#import "SecondController.h"
#import "FirstController.h"

@interface SecondController(){
//stuff
}
@end

@implementation SecondController

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


    NSLog(@"%@",FirstController.levels.answersString);

    // the line above gives me the error "Property 'levels' not found on object of type FirstController

}
@end
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I have tried to create a FirstController object in the SecondController.h, but this does not give me the same property and hence I do not get the right value of the NSString I modified in the first view.

Comment: First Explian what is LevelsCompleted ?.you make things little confusing  as you have imported #import "Model.h" in your FirstViewController class.And you are treating  LevelsCompleted as class,because you are trying to access the NSMutableString *answersString instance by LevelsCompleted instance and setting some value to it.SO explain clearly in which Class you have declared NSMutableString *answersString.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a advice try NSUSERDEFAULT  to access it,.,

Comment: Happy Coding :) a piece of advice buddy ,just go through it .. http://mikeash.com/getting_answers.html

Comment: This is really bad advice. You should NOT use NSUSERDEFAULT to access data between objects. The reason you are having the error is because you are trying to access levels on the class `FirstController.levels` rather than on an instance of that class. See @Saphrosit answer.

Answer (score 1):

`levels` is a instance variable so you cannot access it without instantiating an object first.

You should do something like

```
FirstController *controller = [[FirstController alloc] initWithNibName:@"First" bundle:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",controller.levels.answersString);

[controller release]
```

Comment: This does not work for what I am aiming for; The console prints 'null' instead of '1'. Thanks for answering, but do you have any idea why it still does not work?

Edit: I'll add that I am using ARC, just in case it has something to do with this..?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access another viewcontroller from current viewcontroller directly. Define Level in AppDelagte method and then you can access it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What about moving/adding the `LevelsCompleted *levels` property to the secondviewcontroller and fill `SecondViewcontroller.levels.answerstring` when you use `backbutton:` in you first controller?

Answer (score -1):

By Doing Things As Below you can Achive as You want

Ddeclare  NSMutableString As in your viewController Class As Global variable.
1) LevelsCompleted.h Class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NSMutableString *answersString;// In this way this answersString would accessible through out the  Application and No Need to make property & synthesiz answersString .
@interface LevelsCompleted : UIViewController{

}
```

LevelsCompleted.m Class

//First create that NSMutableString object in its LevelsCompleted.m class

```
#import"LevelsCompleted.h"

@interface LevelsCompleted

-(void)viewDidLoad{

  answersString=[NSMutableString alloc]init];//here created answersString object
 }
@end //end of LevelsCompleted
```

2)FirstController.h class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

extern NSMutableString *answersString;

@interface FirstController : UIViewController{
 // some declarations
}  
@end
```

FirstController.m class

```
#import "FirstController.h"

@implementation FirstController


- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {

// Because i have created that answersString Global in LevelsCompleted.h class 

//we can directly Access and can set the any string Value to that answersString as Below

answersString=@"1";
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];


}

@end
```

SecondController.h  class

```
extern NSMutableString *answersString;// please do this carefully fro getting access the answersString instance 

@interface SecondController:UIViewController{

 //stuff

 }

 @end
```

SecondController.m class

```
@implementation SecondController

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


NSLog(@"%@",answersString);//here you may access easily.
}

@end
```

In above code everything would work because i have done the same thing in my app

just try to catch the concept of extern, global variable .